# Incorrect focusing in chosen jquery plugin in FireFox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

In example, I have two rows. In the first row tabulations work fine, but in the second one I have to press TAB two times to focus next CHOSEN element. I have noticed, that the bug is reproduced in FireFox and only when CHOSEN drop-down-list has a scroll(without it works fine).

Code example: http://jsfiddle.net/streamcode9/fp5pE/

Is it a FireFox or CHOSEN issue? Is it possible to work around it?

Comment: The fiddle linked does not exhibit the problem described. It is possible that Firefox or Chosen has fixed this issue in the time since the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Firefox sets focus on the ul element for the result list. I fixed this by adding `tabindex="-1"` to the `ul` tag in `chosen.jquery.js`.

```
<ul class="chzn-results" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: Can not fix the bug this way now. I think chosen is changed in new versions and that's why it does not work. Do you have up to date answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('select').data('chosen').container.offset().top
});
```

However you need to put your own selector at $('select') based on your project requirement